# How can I write PHP code into JavaScript/Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to know how to write a pice of PHP code into JavaScript/Ajax.

This is my PHP code:

```
   if ($folder = opendir('data/Tasklist/')) {

  while (false !== ($file = readdir($folder))) {
  if ($file != '.' && $file != ".."){


   $data=file_get_contents("data/Tasklist/".$file);

   $poc=explode(";",$data);

  echo '<li class="taskli">
    <button  id="'. $file . '"   class="Del"> Delete </button>
   '. $poc[0] . " " . $poc[1] . '<div class="hidinfo">' . $poc[2] . '</div></li>';

    }
    }
  closedir($handle);
 }
```

And i want to write :    `id="'. $file . '"` inside this code:

```
 $.post( "data/remove.php",{HERE})
```

Comment: Do you mean that when users click on one of the 'Delete' buttons, it should make an AJAX call to the server relating to that file?

Comment: yes @halfer and i want it sent to a new file called remove.php and then delete it from there

Comment: OK, good - @GluePear is on the right lines. Also, it's worth checking that filenames do not create invalid `id` values - files can have all sorts of characters that I expect element ids cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're storing the `$file` variable in the `<button>` id, you can grab it from there:

```
$('.Del').click(function(){
    var file = $(this).attr('id');
    $.post( "data/remove.php",{id:file});
    return false;
});
```

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
          
          $(".Del").click(function(event){

     var file = $('.Del').attr('id');
            $.post( "data/remove.php",{id:file})
      .done(function(id){
      });
  
        
     console.log("delete clicked");
     event.preventDefault();
     return false;
 
         }); 
              });`

Comment: That looks about right, try it? Keep an eye on your JS console to check for errors, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @halfer, I've added the click handler.

Comment: @zan, the one error you have is fixed in GluePear's answer - use `$(this)` to capture the element that raised the event.

Comment: In the console i get no error,i dont know if works or not tho.I must write the code in remove.php also to delete the files i send there.

Comment: You can write a dummy version of remove.php for now: `<?php echo json_encode(array('result' => 'ok')); ?>`. Then you can go back and fix it once the JavaScript is working.

Comment: Also, to see if the AJAX works, check your Monitor console in your developer tools in your browser. You can view your request and response in there. In Firefox for example, it's `Tools -> Web Developer -> Network`.

Comment: this is the [ http://dev.alurosu.com/bobo/Task/tasklist.php ] but when i click delete button now , the task description is opening ,i dont want that , thats why i used event.

Comment: Maybe add `return false;` at the end of the click handler. This might at least stop the description from opening.

Comment: fixed that . btw @halfer u said to use this '<?php echo json_encode(array('result' => 'ok')); ?>'  but i didnt used json.

Comment: @zan, you don't have to use JSON, no - though in my experience it is good to do so, in case you want to return extra information in the future. If you have a JSON reply it means less JS to rewrite.

Comment: @halfer i tried to use json but im new to coding ,i dont know it yet.

Comment: Don't know why the button is submitting the form - buttons don't submit anything anyway. In any case, `event.preventDefault` should have fixed that - debugging required!

Comment: @halfer i didnt used form  


     `Task <input name="task" id="task" >
           Date <input name="date"id="datepicker" type="text" >
     Description <textarea id="desc" value="text">
              </textarea>
        <button id="submit">ADD</button>`